# Is $[u]_m$ a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ if $[u]_n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ divides $m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m,n$ be positive integers with $n$ dividing $m$. We can indeed define a natural surjective map $\varphi$ from ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ by $\varphi([a]_m)=[a]_n$. The problem is:

*Is $\varphi$ still a surjective map when restricted on units of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?*

I've figured out that $\varphi|_{\text{units of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$} }$ as a map is still well-defined. This is because:
for a unit $[u]_m$ of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, there exists $v$ such that $[u]_m[v]_m=[1]_m$. Mod $n$ on both sides we get $[u]_n[v]_n=[1]_n$. The surjective property, however, is not easy for me. I have merely done an example for this. Suppose $n=6$ and $m=12$, the units of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ are $\{[1]_m,[5]_m,[7]_m,[11]_m\}$. the units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are $\{[1]_n,[5]_n\}$. and $[1]_m, [7]_m\mapsto [1]_n$, $[5]_m,[11]_m\mapsto [5]_n$. Hopefully, I guess $[u]_m$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ if $[u]_n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Does this guess make sense and how to judge it?

Thanks for your help and contribution in advance! Any thoughts or discussion are welcomed.

Comment: If $uv=1$ then $\phi(u)\phi(v)=\phi(1)=1$, so units are mapped to units if $\phi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. The latter was shown in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233230/showing-that-varphi-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-rightarrow-mathbbz-m-mathbbz?rq=1).

Comment: Counterexample: $2$ is a unit  in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$ and a zero-divisor in $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$. It would  work if $m$ and $n$ have the same set of prime factors.

Comment: @Bernard True, thank you! The surjective property, however, still holds if we consider $[5]_6\mapsto [2]_3$, both being units in their modular rings.

Comment: I only gave a counterexample to the question of your title!

Comment: @Bernard Indeed, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!